# implemantation of facebook like button

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am developing a site with html and php ...

what i have done so far for like button on my page is as follow(concept is same only name is different on facebook it is like and on my site it is Points Up )

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $posts[postid]; ?>" name="postid">
<input type="submit" name="pointsup" value="Points Up" />
</form>
```

the above will create the button with name Points Up.

`if(isset($_POST['pointsup']))
{ in this if block i have written all queries to update database and user interface and all
}`

what i want is instead of that button there should be some link witch will run my sql code.

i also tried JavaScript but it doesn't help anything

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You can use ajax. here is article: http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with a single anchor tag (hyperlink), you should send your parameters by GET method. in case, `/your/address/rate.php?id=` and check `$_GET['id']` in PHP (validate/sanitize/...)

also, you can send your requests as POST by using AJAX.
this is a sample for jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

but if you want to use pure JavaScript, you should work with **XMLHttpRequest** object. take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

1. Find where you should point your link to and what parameters are needed, i will call it $url. It can involve such things like creating additional files, refactoring your code, etc...
2. Write js method which will send request to $url. I will call this method sendPointsUp;
3. Create link which will react to onClick event and call sendPointsUp with desired parameters from there.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just add a link with an id so you can reach it easily with jquery.
Create a php-page where you do the query and other stuff (security check, cookie, whatever you want to do), and finally attach an ajax event to the link to call your php-page.

Print the link in your page:

```
<a href="" id="voteup">Vote up</a>
```

Create php

```
<?php
  // do the query and other stuff, return the result in json format
  // if you want to do something with the result (for example display the votes)
```

Javascript

```
$('#voteup').click(function(e){
  $.ajax({
  url: "your/url/to/phpfile",
}).done(function(data) { 
  // rewrite link to undo vote or whatever you want
  // do something with the returned data
});
});
```